# How to make a switch draggable/clickable on modern desktop and mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilg4q.jpg. Where you will drag/click the switch and it will stick to either the on or off position. Very similar to this example I found - http://codepen.io/stevenfabre/pen/qpBDy. Problem is that in the example dragging doesn't work on mobile.

All the examples of switches I've seen so far use JQuery UI which would be nice to avoid if possible because I wouldn't need anything else in the library other than the `draggable` method.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I currently use JQuery and Foundation and my goal was to not add any more libraries. My final solution was to hack the foundation slider to a switch button. http://codepen.io/anthony-dandrea/pen/XbOmoG

Definitely not a clean solution but the hack was simple enough that it will work for what I need. If anyone knows of a better way using those tools or some small library please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using foundation and ended up hacking together a draggable switch.

```js
// Init for foundation
$(document).foundation();

// Turns foundation range into a switch
$(document).ready(function() {
 var isDown;
 // Slider begins to move 
 $('[data-slider]').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  isDown = true;
 });

 // Let go of slider event
 $(document).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
  if (isDown) {
   isDown = false;
   var $switch = $('[data-slider]');
   var val = $switch.attr('data-slider');

   if (val > 50) {
    // On
    $switch.foundation('slider','set_value', 100);
   } else {
    // Off
    $switch.foundation('slider','set_value', 0);
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
}

.range-slider-handle {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.5.0/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="range-slider vertical-range" data-slider data-options="vertical: true; initial: 0;">
  <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
  <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Boostrap CSS/JS? I would recommend using Bootstrap Switch if you are looking for a lightweight solution and are already using Bootstrap.
http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

You can also browse through examples of modified switches to see how to change their look (and to turn it on the side if you like). http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html

The switch just requires standard jQuery and not jQuery UI.If you already have jQueryand Bootstrap, then you can load the bootstrap-switch.js file and be set to go.

Comment: Awesome, http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ is exactly the functionality I want. I'm not using bootstrap. I am using JQuery however. Do you know if there's a non bootstrap option or library? Or if there's a way to customize it to only contain this switch functionality I need?

Comment: Well technically yes, but you would have to extract the code from the Bootstrap.js file. More work than its worth. I always use a minified Bootstrap.js file so loading time doesn't become a huge issue. And switches like these will always require a JS library so you might as well use one that has other beneficial features. You can also check out Zurb Foundation as its also highly used.

Comment: I'm actually using foundation. But I couldn't find any libs for making the switch in foundation draggable. Only could see click to switch.

Comment: Oh yea I always thought Foundation was a bit more difficult to use. But I highly recommend Bootstrap, from their CSS to JS its all very simple, well-documented, and extensible. Which means you find many other people's bootstrap code that can make UI components like these function and look differently (kind of like the examples page in my answer). If the switch is not draggable by default then you would need to add the jquery UI draggable method and that can get messy if you don't have an example to work off of.